# If $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers from $1$ to $100$, how many pairs of numbers $(a,b)$ are there which satisfy $a^{\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{a^b}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> > If $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers from $1$ to $100$, how many pairs of numbers $(a,b)$ are there which satisfy $a^{\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{a^b}$

This was from a math contest I did earlier today and I was completely stumped how to solve this!

Other than the trivial $a=1=b$ and when $b=4$ then $a \in [1,100]$

Which means there are $101$ cases but are there any more?

Comment: You have $98$ more for $a = 1$ and $b$ arbitrary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$a^{\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{a^b}$$

Squaring both sides,

$$a^{2\sqrt{b}}=a^b$$

Case 1: $a=1$. It holds regardless of $b$. ($100$ cases)

Case 2: If $a \neq 1$, $2\sqrt{b}=b \implies b=4$ ($99$ cases)

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\sqrt{a^b}=(a^b)^{1/2}=a^{b/2}$.  If $a>1$, then $a^{\sqrt{b}}=a^{b/2}$ iff $\sqrt{b}=b/2$, which happens only for $b=4$.  On the other hand, if $a=1$, then $b$ can be anything and both sides will be $1$.  So the solutions are $(1,b)$ for any $b$ and $(a,4)$ for any $a$.  There are $100$ solutions in each of these cases, but both cases include $(1,4)$, so you get $199$ solutions in total.